# Will this laptop LCD missing one of the connector pads work?

Tags: display, displayport, laptop-repair, connector

I removed the broken display connector from an LED screen. As can be seen in the following image, the pad for pin 27 is removed from the PCB due to an accident. I've marked it with red color in the image.

[image]

Since multimeter shows that the resistance between pads 26, 28 and 29 is 0.0 Ohms, I think that the pads 26-29 (including the missing pad 27) are all for backlight power according to the following image, so the LCD should work with one pad missing, though the other pads/pins may get warmer/hotter than usual. But before installing a new 30-pin connector I'd like to know what people with more experience think about this issue.

[image]

Comment: I have these pads in electronic equipment with displays as well as computers. They tend to be different . All you can really do is try if you do not want to replace the pad.

Comment: Likely it would work as-is, but that pin-out shows that 26-29 are connected together to backlight B+. If it *doesn't* work with pad 27 disconnected ("floating"), you could try bridging a short piece of wire between 26 and 28, and connect cable 27 to that bridge, so that it is not floating.